What is the purpose of WB:SE? - Are we a "HowTo" for worldbuilding?
Important Clarification
Please read the following in the light of "How can we guide a new user to ask good questions".
Not in the light of "a proposal to change what SE or WB:SE is about or how it works" - that is not the intent!
Background
I have put a lot of thought in the concept of WB:SE recently, since I realized that there are fundamental contradictions in how WB:SE is used or seen by "users/questioneers/querers" and "curators/answerers/experts/us".
There is also the point of an open opportunity to streamline the help-pages which can outline what we are expecting here on WB:SE. And it would be a pity if we do not facelift that.
Introduction
At this point I would like to propose a concept of WB:SE which might bring us further.
Please consider: This proposal is not meant to be the "only" purpose of WB:SE. The intention is for the final state to collect all those concepts in a way that we can present them to the outside world in order to allow users to use the platform as a safe haven of "I have a concern and need experts" as well as us, being the experts, and need to convey a clear view of what we are capable of providing.
The proposal at hand touches the point of "open endedness" and "brainstorming" and "too plot-specific". Especially by the input and discussion with @sphennings (thank you at this point!), I was put into the right direction, I think.
Problem Identification
What was often criticised was that the questions were "too specific to one use case" and the "questioner should ask "differently" and the answers should be "useful for later knowledge seekers". And also, the notion of "we would rather explain the principles instead of a solution for one person".
Possible Way of handling it
It struck me, that there is a name for that: Having a "HowTo Worldbuilding"

"HowTo... determine that my binary merge system is plausible?"

Requires expert help from (Astro-)Physicists
Answers can explain how gravity and other factors will affect the situations. This is a complicated field, so we should also focus on:
Answers will simplify the mechanics at hand to a point that also a beginner (and outside reader) is able to draw advantage from WB:SE. In this case:

Derive the final formula that allows determine the distance of two bodies, given their weight.
Or derive a formula for determine the weight of the central body (in planet masses), given one planet mass and the requirement of having a X days year (assuming circular orbits, or even elliptical if someone can figure this out)


The best answer? Well, that which is able to explain it simple enough to be acceptable.
The good part is that answers can profit from other answers.

One can maybe provide Newtons Law as a starting point.
The next answer shows how to apply this law to the system at hand using variables and identify things that are known/have to be fixed (habitable zone for example).
Another could mention something else to consider.
The next provides details on that again. And so on.





Applying to other fields and special cases
The example is from physics. But I think there can be similar structures for biology and other fields as well. "HowTo... determine that my creature is of the right size for my planet?", "HowTo determine that the eyes of my creature needs to have slit or round pupils?", "HowTo determine if my capital city will influence the surrounding area?"
If there is not a known way of "HowTo determine X" then this is also a valid answer (maybe not the true answer, but given enough time and experts, maybe there will be other discoveries later).
At this point there would be no need for bashing the OP for being "too plot relevant". Just tell him: "There is currently no science field (that I know of) that covers this topic. You are free to make something up". Perfect answer backed by an expert('s opinion), isn't it?
So my question is:
Is a "How-To" concept for WB:SE something to endorse?

Can it be fleshed out?
What are your concerns?
Do you not care, thus would you do what the majority thinks is best?

(Keep in mind, it is not intended to be the "only" concept. Just for starters, let's scrutinize the "How-To" concept).
(Also keep in mind that this would not need any changes on the SE software. It is just a way to communicate to the outside, how good questions are (or can be) formed.)
Addendum: Q&A in HowTo-style (that could make you smile)

How would intelligent AI in virtual reality discover machine code?
How to make fail-safe for full body virtual reality?
How to defeat an AI wizard? (not as positive; interesting corner case)


My experience suggests that anything we can write a cogent, and more importantly objectively correct, "HowTo" about boils down to "here are three online calculator tools that will all do that for you" with or without our own take on how they should be used. Whenever I work on questions about astrophysics I have a short catalogue of calculator websites that I go to, I put in the numbers, I present the results, that's it, a HowTo answer would simply consist of "go here" possibly with a "do this", and anything that we can't boil down to a mathematical equation cannot be objectively correct.

Wouldn't this be totally awesome if this knowledge about the calculators and tools would be prominently accessible? No need for those quesions anymore (or only for special cases). Most users could help themselves. -- You are certainly right in terms of "calulating something". But what about a question like "How To figure out capitol influence to its nearby villages?" - Each answer would present one best practice to apply. - The "best" answer is always case dependent on the user that reads it. One is happy about a kind of checklist what to look for. The other loves details about speceifics.@Ash

Anyone can already help themselves, I find them with Google when I need them, so can anyone else who knows what they're asking about, I pull the key words for the tool I need straight from the question. There is no "best practice" for that question, it's proper answer is based wholly in the universe it inhabits, without a FULL run down of the history and technology of the setting there's no basis for an accurate answer whatsoever or at all.

@Ash Because you know how to do it and also think anybody can do it, does not make it covering the truth. Why is there so much traffic on Q&A if nobody actually should have a need for Q because they can get their A on their own? The Q&A is for those who cannot. For those who seek help. Exactly the opposite of those who know how to, because those are the ones sitting here and could provide answers. No question really asks for a "full 100% complete" answer - they just can be read that way. Because users are notoriously bad at formulating them, does not mean they are demanding the impossible.

I always wonder why people show up here with those questions, especially when we specifically encourage research before asking a question, because they clearly haven't taken the simple step of Googling "how do I calculate X?". I tend not to take a nice tone in those answers. MANY questions ask for a perfect 100% answer, it should be most or all the way it is in other stacks but we're more lenient around here.

Changing the Help Center is a non-trivial process
There is very little about the Help Center that can be modified or changed by the WB.SE moderators. An effort is underway to update those portions of the Help Center that we can modify. We're at the very beginning of that process. You can find two questions that have been asked so far under the 2024-hc-redesign tag. The process is intentionally slow because (a) most of us work for a living and (b) we want people to have plenty of time to consider what they want because we don't want to change the Help Center again for years and years.
Having said that, and I want to be very clear about this, you are not welcome to use that tag without gaining Moderator approval. With a whopping 37 days under your belt you will cause more problems than you will solve.
How-To is harder than it sounds
Remember what I said about who owns the service and who wrote most of the rules? Stack Exchange, Inc. has specific ideas about how questions are to be asked and answered. WB.SE is almost unique in how fantastically subjective it is compared nearly all other stacks that fit the SE mold very well.
The problem with "how-to" answers is that they're intrinsically subjective. One person uses one method, another uses another. Neither method is particularly better than the other — and we just violated a Help Center rule (no questions leading to answers having equal value) that we have no power to modify.
So... this doesn't work, either.
You're trying to recreate a ten-year-old service in your own 37-day-old image. You'll find some people agree with you — but most won't.

I cannot see any questions under that tag. Maybe they are protected somehow. That I am "only" 37days here "actively" participating does not mean, I do not know the site. I do not endorse how the site treats people, that is true. Thank you for your time to answer this question. It is at least constructive and more enlightening than just downvoting ;)

Huh. I never knew that clicking on a tag link always threw you out to Main. Tags for Meta are separate from tags for Main. Try here.

Oh I see/didn't notice. Thank you! That worked. @JBH

Sonofagun... there's a different magic link for Meta tags. [meta-tag:tag-name] For a list of magic links, see here

@Antares Unfortunately being only 37 days in does mean you don't really know the site, that's long enough to read a lot of the official stuff, get a feel for current trends etc... but on this site precedent matters, sometimes more than we'd like it to. There are archived, and sometimes even deleted, chat conversations and meta posts from years ago that still alter how things work away from the official line and often against expectations. I took a long break, only came back in May and the changes in question goalposts were quite marked, 90 odd days later I still feel a little off balance.

No. What Is Stack Exchange, Anyway?

We were all in your place at one time in the past. Five or six weeks in. Everything is new and exciting. Until we got bonked by some mean and rude older user who tried to shove a bunch of useless rules down our throats and told us scathingly that we're doing it all wrong! Some of us end up leaving in a huff --- what a rude bunch of people! Not at all like Reddit, where everyone is kind and compassionate and everyone's questions are accepted without any rules, guidelines or policy restrictions at all! Every worldbuilding forum should be like this!

Yeah. Well, in many ways Reddit sucks. Too many of its "moderators" are cliquish children who will ban people on a whim and there is simply no sense of community involvement or moderation. You can often find good answers there, and loads of useful discussion. Especially if you already know about the topic and can sift wheat from chaff.

I suspect that if more people actually read what Stack Exchange is, some time in their first days or week of finding this place, we'd have a lot fewer disgruntled users, we'd have a lot fewer unhelpful comments & discussions, we'd have a lot fewer instances of people trying to invent the horse carriage when the rest of us are sipping tea on the transcon maglev.

We'd certainly have a much more educated userbase! People who have read and understood SE's distinctives are more likely to transition from new to experienced member more smoothly and are less likely to feel unwelcome.

Stack Exchange is Different --- We aren't like Quora or Reddit or even an awesome worldbuilding forum like CBB. There is a method to the madness, and unfortunately many users never come to grips with this fact. Not just new users, but also long time members just don't get what this entire platform is about.

It may seem harsh, it may seem arbitrary, and we may seem rude saying these things for the 549,263rd time, but we don't do certain things here:

We don't discuss. This isn't a chat forum. We're not here to discuss your world, no matter how awesome it is.
We don't brainstorm. This is not a discussion forum. This is not a brainstorming forum.
We don't do handholding. This is not the place for you if you're just starting out in worldbuilding! You need to know enough about your fictional world to even ask a sensible question type here!
We don't do lists. Period. This is not a brainstorming session.
We don't write books. No querent in the history of WB.SE has ever paid me enough to write a chapter about their world, let alone an entire book.
We don't do excessively broad or purely opinionated questions. Take those to Reddit.
We don't do How To. Take that to Youtube.
We don't do storycraft. Plot, character formation, narrative: take all of that to Writing.SE.
We don't do your homework for you. Querents are expected to come here with some research already done.
We don't do real world questions. Querents are expected to understand that there are other SE forums for these questions.
User experience here is 100% user driven. When you actively use the SE service, you need to follow their rules! The failure of any user to comply is not our problem.

In our little corner of Stack Exchange, we do precisely one thing, and one thing only.

We DO answer worldbuilding queries that are single topic, well focused, and amenable to a very small number of acceptable answers. (And we're very lenient on this!) The Stack Exchange Model can literally be destilled down to: one discrete, super-focused, narrowly constrained query gets one objectively superior answer.


What does this mean for you? --- Since you are new here, Antares, and really seem keen to hang around and play an active role here in WB.SE. I would really like to invite you to read and absorb that link. Keeping in mind that WB.SE does not belong to us --- we're here at the pleasure of Stack Exchange Inc. They founded and created this platform. They determined how it would function. They determined the underlying rule sets and policies. I am not exactly certain by what grace or miracle this little forum got allowed to exist, but we're here now! Our job as the more active community moderators is to discern and strike the balance between the black-letter law established by SE and the needs of a community such as ours that differ often radically from the needs of other forums.

When we speak of closure reasons and when we get after people for "breaking the rules", please understand that we're not behaving in an arbitrary fashion. We don't close questions because we don't like people. We don't close questions because we don't like the question. When we close questions, 98% of the time it's clear that the querent did something wrong according to the system established by Stack Exchange Inc.

The alternative is that SE closes our forum because we're not upholding SE rules, norms, customs, guidelines, etc.

I'd also like to invite you to read through the Meta questions of the last couple years especially. Pay close attention to the "why was my question closed" type; and pay close attention to anything that looks like a WB.SE specific policy (like "high concept question", "book test", "narrative necessity", "frame challenge", "real world question", "closure reasons", "discussion based", "opinion based", etc.)

You'll start to see the bigger picture. My hope is that you'll eventually come to realise that all the policies we've got, all the community customs, all the guidelines, all the meta discussions exist for one sole reason. And that is to provide a place where worldbuilders can come to ask questions and receive answers from knowledgeable people who are passionate about worldbuilding. And all of this within the rigid SE structure, modified as best we can to suit the particular needs of a community whose questions often break that rigid structure.

This is a definition of WB:SE I would like to see on the help center page (especially the bullet points). And also on the "Ask Question" page (if it would be possible; I know it isn't). No fogging. Just plain, direct stating what is and what is not considered "allowed/good". -- What I realize now is that my "HowTo" concept is misleading, bc I thought this to be a concise way of telling: Ask "How To" questions. Not "Can I ..." etc. -- but it reads strongly like "converting SE/WB:SE" into something else instead of giving it a purpose definition -- But nvm, I am grateful for your feedback!

@Antares We literally can't change that part of the Help Center. We have one portion we may edit somewhat freely: the "what is on topic" portion. Anything else? Pre-written by Stackexchange Inc.

@Trish: I mean this page: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic - maybe "help center" was the wrong term?

Those points in this answer? all in the on-topic.

@Trish: Nah... It is broken in the first sentence already: "Worldbuilding Stack Exchange is a site for designers, writers, artists, gamers and enthusiasts to get help creating imaginary worlds."  --- while this is maybe the intention this sentence already invites everybody to ask everything... nothing to read of: "No brainstorming." - "brainstorming" is mentioned somewhere in the last paragraph at the very bottom of the page. I really mean those bulletpoints as in: prominent, first thing to read. Not hidden "somewhere" on that page.

@Antares --- 1. I literally read the Tour from Stack Exchange itself and recomposed it here. The bullet points are literally condensed from several of our policies. These aren't definitional! And even if they were, it would be of no use in the Help Center, because the definition we want there is for worldbuilding, not for WB.SE!  2. "Fogging". The problem here is that you're asking for ephemeral policy statements to enshrined as definitional. Those policies can (and likely will) change some day.  Our policy about real world questions is probably one of the more volatile and I'd (cont)

(cont) expect that one to go back and forth in the future. 3. The page you linked to, "What topics..." --- that can indeed be discussed! If you'd like to open a discussion here in Meta, please feel free! 4. That sentence, "WB.SE is a site for designers..." --- that is what we're discussing in the definition thread! The point isn't to tell people what they can or can't do in that little blurb. That blurb is what's known as an "elevator pitch". A short statement of what our activity is and what it's all about!

I feel I ought to weigh-in here, especially since my most recent question has poured fuel on this particular topic.
So - first things first, Yes, I have posted a question that, from a certain viewpoint, would go against the rules. Too open, too broad, brainstorming etc.
Yet, I justify the existence of the question (and answer) to be in the spirit of the rules.
I will forgo a series of lengthy examples on what I mean by this - simply put - I believe that the Question and Answer is in-keeping with what SE:WB is. A Place for people to ask questions and get answers about World Building. The question I wrote was a Meta-Question and then I posted my Answer. Some others have chimed in with some fantastic Answers of their own.
A potential World Builder who is struggling with a problem on how to write something Military related can read the answers and either get inspired with a solution or use the points to more clearly articulate a good question for this SE.
Thus, IMO, the quality of the site has improved.
The next point - Yes, I am getting lee-way and preferential treatment owing to the fact I have numbers next to my name and regularly contribute. Those that are on the Mod team know who I am, probably read the original post in Meta etc.
If you want to complain that the time I have spent here has earned me a certain amount of discretion that you have not yet earned - then Sorry, not sorry (I dont wish to sound mean)
Now, to answer the question
WB exists in its own very special niche, we are probably one of the most subjective SE out there. Things that are designed for SE core audience (IT Nerds) dont work well here and vice-versa - This is JBHs comment - that whilst many things would be nice-to-haves for us, we are small and an afterthought, so we cannot do it easily.
That all said, as evidenced by the fact I wrote a big long question and answer and submitted it to Meta first for review, then after some discussion posted it to the main site - I think there is some scope for what you are after. Military issues is something that I felt we were seeing enough of a similar type of problem that a good meta-question could be written. You could perhaps do something similar with Politics if you were brave enough (I am not) and some other common scenarios.
I think the other posters are giving you a bit of a harder-time than perhaps is warranted, probably more borne out of the same frustrations that you expressed and the inability to change them.
And so - to answer the question directly:
Whilst we are not a how-to site, with some topics there are common enough questions that in some instances, extracting out a Meta-Question and giving answers on how to address that Meta-Question IS in-line with SE overall ethos, despite seemingly running foul of some of the rules here.
Such questions and answers add to the overall value of the SE, rather than detract from it.

I try to pull a constructive conclusion from your feedback (thank you!): If there can be a How-To superstructure on WB:SE, the way to go would be: Someone creates a Meta-Question, curates it over an extended period of time, then when of high enough value, post a introductory question in main and answer it by the content of the Meta-Question. This would be a process I would totally understand and encourage for the "HowTo" idea. It just should be made transparent that this exists. And maybe also a collection of those HowTos like the Knowledgebase (learned about that post through yours)

I'd like to point out though, that from my perspective the main collaboration took place in main, not in meta. So maybe it should not curated in meta forever but realeased to main to gather more input on it.

There's noting wrong with asking questions about military issues. However one of the fundamental guidelines of every Stack Exchange site is that if to fully answer a question would require writing a book on the topic it isn't appropriate for the site. The question you asked could cover many many books to be fully answered. As such it should not be asked on the main site. Had you narrowed down your scope to ask about a much more specific aspect of military worldbuilding then (as I said in my comment to your question) it would be an excellent addition to this site.

@sphennings - I hear your critique and I think there are some elements of it that are true. So far, there have been some good answers, but even my big answer - nothing that is truly book worthy. I would say that because we are assuming a base-level of World Building understanding and tackling most of the high-level World Building issues with Military WB, that constrains the question, In my opinion.

Relying on assumptions isn’t a good way to share knowledge. Good answers to an overly broad question aren’t searchable in a way that is useful to later worldbuilders. You post runs contrary to the fundamental design philosophy of this site.
